# Сортировка массива

Tags: c#, c, c++

Нужно отсортировать массив целых любых чисел методом бульбашки.
Данный код:

```
bool exit = false; // болевая переменная для выхода из цикла, если массив отсортирован

        while (!exit) // пока массив не отсортирован
        {
            exit = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < (sizearr - 1); i++) // внутренний цикл
                //сортировка пузырьком по возрастанию - знак >
                //сортировка пузырьком по убыванию - знак <
                if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) // сравниваем два соседних элемента
                {
                    // выполняем перестановку элементов массива
                    swap(arr[i + 1], arr[i]);
                    exit = false; // на очередной итерации была произведена перестановка элементов
                }
        }
```

Зависает.

Вот этот:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizearr; i++)
{
    for (int j = sizearr - 1; j > i; j--)
    {
        if (arr[j] < arr[j - 1])
        {
            swap(arr[j], arr[j - 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Неправильно сортирует. Например, входной массив:

```
92, 77, 89, 6, 27, 60, 61, 20, 54, 24, 37, 4, 72, 86, 47, 35, 57, 61, 87, 81, 33, 69, 29, 58, 45, 34, 36, 71, 3, 29
```

Исходный:

```
92, 77, 89, 6, 27, 60, 61, 20, 54, 24, 37, 4, 72, 86, 47, 35, 57, 61, 87, 81, 33, 69, 29, 58, 45, 34, 36, 71, 3, 29
```

Comment: Да, оба варианта реализации неправильны. А какой из них ваш?

Comment: 1. болевая?
2. Нужно отсортировать - сортируйте. Куча примеров:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Bubble_sort#C_2
Если вдруг изменится или появится собственно у Вас вопрос по теме/в сообщении - ответим

Comment: @Богдан Бессонов, пример C 2 не работает.
Например: входные данные 19, 46, 2, 84, 35, 70, 35, 51, 99, 39, 49, 80, 81, 81, 36, 47, 1, 3, 63, 83, 98, 31, 95, 49, 75, 70, 33, 1, 5, 97. И выходные такие же. Я не знаю почему.

Comment: Полностью код, с примером с2, допишите в тему, я верю, что пример с википедии работает. Вернее он у меня вот только что отлично работал.

Comment: Два вопроса. На каком языке это все 2. Это компилируется нормально? Ошибок компиляции нет?
А то в вопросе заявлен с++, а выглядит как си шарп

Comment: Да это си шарп. В вопроса написал дополнительные языки, потому что алгоритм то один. Компилирует нормально.

Comment: @andrei1610, пишите на обычном Си и у Вас все начнет получаться.

Comment: @andrei1610, Вы бы выкладывали код куда-нибудь, что бы его не качать. 

Например, в pastebin.com (или прямо в свой вопрос весь скопипстьте).

Comment: @avp, http://pastebin.com/s7PPBH4M Перед этим выложил как архив, потому что там был и класс формы

Comment: @avp, действительно заработало. кто бы мог подумать, что проблема может возникнуть в месте обмена значения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А что это

```
swap(arr[i + 1], arr[int_counter]);
```

у Вас?

И скорее всего ошибка в том, что swap() это функция, которую мы не видим и ее аргументы описаны неправильно (в результате **значения в массиве** не меняются местами) .

Напишите SWAP через макрос или закодируйте в лоб (как в последнем примере) и все заработает.

--

Кстати, метод можно чуть ускорить

```
 int j = 0;
 while (!exi) {
   exi = 0; j++; 
   for (i = 0; i < sizearr - j; i++)
     // далее по тексту.
```

Это работает, поскольку на каждой итерации "подбирается" самый большой элемент и "тащится" до конца.

Замените это

```
 _swap(arr[i + 1], arr[i]);
```

на его "тело"

```
  {
     int t = arr[i + 1];
     arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
     arr[i] = t;
  }
```

и все заработает (собственно, я уже писал (угадал) это в своем комментарии).

--

У меня комментарии закончились (здесь лимит -- 4 шт).

Все дело в том, что параметры в функции передаются **именно по значению**, а не по адресу.

Почитайте в учебнике повнимательней этот момент.